# Pandas Dataframe Transpose

Tags: python, pandas

I have tried to find something that could help me but I couldn't. I'd appreciate if someone could link me to it, if my question is already answered.

I have a pandas dataframe that has row-wise features. For example:

```
   Patient_ID  Feature_Id  Feature_Value
0           3          10           0.30
1           3          50           0.20
2           3          60           1.00
3           4          10           0.25
```

I need to convert them into column-wise features(essentially columns in Pandas) -- something like below:

```
Patient_Id    10   50   60
         3  0.30  0.2  1.0
         4  0.25  Nan  Nan
```

Comment: @ayhan sorry can you point me to some help how you formatted the tables in here?

Comment: You can directly paste your DataFrame here and click on `{ }` while the DataFrame is selected. It will format it as code. I've removed `|` character and used empty lines, that's all. You can click on [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39437387/edit) to see the current markdown.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [`pd.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html)

```
In [16]: pd.pivot_table(df, index='Patient_ID', values='Feature_Value', columns='Feature_ID')
Out[16]: 
Feature_ID    10   50   60
Patient_ID                
3           0.30  0.2  1.0
4           0.25  NaN  NaN
```

Note that if you need to specify what to do if more than a single entry exists (which you don't have in your example), you can use the `aggfunc` parameter (the default is to calculate the mean).

Comment: I'm required to run feature selection techniques on the row-wise columns. I'm finding it hard to do that, so converting them to columns. It's not ideal, because the matrix is extremely sparse. Is there a method I could find correlation statistics for the features while they are in Feature_Id column?

Comment: @Ahsan Not sure I understood between what exactly are you trying to find correlations. Could you try `df.T.corr()`, and specify further if that's not what you're trying to do?

Comment: Feature_Id column has all the features to classify certain subjects. There are thousands of features and I'm thinking I could select the one's that contribute more towards selection of the right label. Labels are binary. Thus, perhaps trying to find the correlation between features and the dependent variable(label) might help. That's the idea anyway for now.

Comment: @Ahsan There are easier ways to do this using `scipy`, but here's one way to do it using `numpy`: `import numpy as np`, then `dict([(c, np.corrcoef(df[c], df['Feature_Value'])[0][1]) for c in df.columns if c != 'Feature_Value'])`. It should return a map of the feature's corrcoeff with the dependent variable. From there you can change it to any other data structure easily.